# how to add expires headers in magento

Tags: php, javascript, ce-1.8.1.0, css, html

I analyzed my website on Gtmetrix.com for optimization and the result was this:

> There are 4 static components without a far-future expiration date:

```
http://www.someextensionsite.com/widgets/v1.0/init.js
http://static.someextensionsite.com/templates.0p4D3v0p5f.js
http://static.someextensionsite.com/styles.0p4D3v0p5f.css
http://static.someextentionsite.com/preload_data.0p4D3v0p5f.js
```

> Expires headers let the browser know whether to server a cached
>   version of the page.

*and i should add this: someextentionsite is a search extentin.*

how to solve this problem?

Comment: You can check this link for adding expiry headers in Magento: http://www.lissori.com/blog/magento/magento-speed-tips-expires-headers/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about communicating with your search service provider to configure their servers better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't control the domains

- www.someextensionsite.com
- static.someextensionsites.com

therefore you can't do anything to fix this error.

Answer (score 13):

Try to put this in .htaccess

```
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>
```

Comment: Only difference for me from [this post](http://serverfault.com/questions/86188/configuring-favicon-with-expires-header-in-htaccess) was a small tweak for the favicon `AddType image/x-icon .ico`

Comment: The default htaccess already contains`ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"`, what is missing is `ExpiresActive On` - if that's not on by default